# Grails: Using the Resources plugin in a plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, resources

I'm trying to use the Resources plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/resources) in a plugin that I'm developing, however, I can't seem to get it to work.  I keep getting error messages that the module (defined in the ApplicationResources.groovy file) doesn't exist when it tries to render the gsp file.  Only if I add the module to the Grails application's (that my plugin is being used in) ApplicationResources.groovy file does this error message go away.  Clearly the Resources plugin is only looking at the application files, and not the plugin files.  Is this a known issue?  Is there a solution or work around to be able to use the Resources plugin in a plugin?

Comment: You have to add the module from the plugin into your app's module or you can require the plugin module directly in the gsp. This is how resources plugin works. If each of the module present in plugin starts working by itself app will not have control over the resources. Moreover, try to rename `ApplicationResources.groovy` in the plugin to `MyPluginResources.groovy`, obviously MyPlugin will be name of the actual plugin.

Comment: The suggestion to rename the file fixed my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply renamed the ApplicationResources.groovy file to MyPluginResources.groovy (where MyPlugin is the name of the plugin) and the problem went away.